# Anding test for 3 bits of port on pic not working

Tags: port, bit, logical-operators

i am flashing an led, but if i detect that 3 port pins all have 0 on them, Anding the result all to zero, i wish the led to stop flashing. But why doesnt this work?

```
    if (RB3 && RB4 && RB5 == 0){
    RB6  = RB6;
    }
    else
    RB6  = !RB6;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (RB3 && RB4 && RB5 == 0)
```

Although this reads like you want it to, it does not mean what you expect.

What you want:

```
if ((RB3 == 0) && (RB4 == 0) && (RB5 == 0))
```

Answer (score -1):

which compiler are you using?

Are you sure that RB3, RB4, RB5 and RB6 are exactly what you mean?

With CSS compiler you have to use this syntax:

```
int b6;
...
if ( (input(PIN_B3) && input(PIN_B4) && input(PIN_B5)) != 0) { b6 = !b6; }
output_bit(PIN_B6, b6);
```